# OnMouseMoved Android?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, onmousemove

I am learning how to make android apps, and I can't figure out how to implement a kind of OnMouseMoved event in android.

I've tried using an OnTouchListener, but It doesn't update when I touch, hold and move. It only updates when I tap a different points. Like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    thread.getGameState().touch(x);
    return false;
}
```

I've tried this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        thread.getGameState().touch(x);
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this doesn't even respond at all to touch, maybe the point i'm getting from the event is an old point, and not the new drag point?

`thread.getGameState().touch(x);` sets the x-value of and object, which should make it like dragging.

Comment: this is covered pretty well in the android docs http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html  .. maybe take a look at that as a starting point

Comment: may i know how will you attach mouse with your android device?

Comment: @Gunaseelan USB?  Bluetooth?

Comment: wow! it is nice to see we can connect mouse with android device. Thank you so much @Simon

Comment: No I meant to input touch, not a mouse

Answer (score 0):

You must return true in `onTouch()` to tell Android that you will handle the complete touch event, so you can receive events after `ACTION_DOWN`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        thread.getGameState().touch(x);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't detect it still